# Is it really important to close PdfReader?

Tags: vb.net, itext

I'm writing a class with a PdfReader for parameter.
Then I'm executing some functions like find placeholder, change the placeholder but I create a new file for this function, I don't want to overwrite the initial pdf. I want to close the PdfReader, only when I'm done with this Pdf.

I already wrote the code and that work. But I want to know if I really have to initialise and close the PdfReader in each function.

Thank you beforehand,
ElFranchoute.

Comment: Why that? You can hold an instance of the PdfReader in your class and let this class implement `IDisposable`. Dispose the `PdfReader` in the `Dispose`-method. Then you can create and use an instance of your class with the `using`-statement. So no need to initialise and close it everywhere.

Comment: Because I want to read It only one time, after that the content of the pdf is saved in the reader, then i can just use it. Or I think that work like that.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what problem you are trying to solve or get around but I can tell you that _not_ calling `Close()` on the `PdfReader` bound to a file will cause that file to be locked for writing/deleting until that object goes out of scope and is automatically handle by the runtime. My personal style is that I'd rather not have two classes aware of third-party libraries if I can so I'd rather have one class that passes a string (file path) to another class that creates and "owns" the `PdfReader`. If you want to avoid the lock, however, you can just use `PdfReader` with a byte array instead.

Comment: Hello Chris, that is what I already do, but I want to do it like `Private pdfFileReader As PdfReader(file)` and then I use this object with my functions. But I don't know when I have to use the `close()` function.
If it's possible, i want to use it, when I don't need more this pdfReader.